# SEM Diagram and Measurement Invariance

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

[Vandenberg & Lance (2000)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/109442810031002) explain that measurement invariance in SEM is important because the variance-covariance matrix of a group, $\Sigma$, and item scores, $X$, can be decomposed, such that

$$X_k^g=\tau_k^g+\Lambda_k^g\xi^g+\delta_k^g$$

and

$$\Sigma^g=\Lambda_X^g\Phi^g\Lambda_X'^{g}+\Theta_\delta^g$$

where $g$ is a group identifier, $k$ is a variable identifier, $\tau$ is an intercept, $\lambda$ is a regression slope relating $X$ to $\xi$, $\delta$ are unique factors, $\Lambda$ is an item's factor loadings on the latent factor $\xi$, $\Phi$ is the variance-covariance among $\xi$, and $\Theta$ is the unique variance to an item.

Is my diagram below correct in representing this relationship? I expect the $\delta$ and $\theta$ parts are incorrect, so I am unsure of how to diagram them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've drawn the diagram a little unconventionally, for example you've only drawn one indicator, and  $\Phi$ is often irrelevant when you're looking at invariance, so it is not modelled. $\theta$ is usually thought of as being equal to 1, and so can also be ignored / removed.

Apart from that, looks OK to me.